# Which component of bootstrap will be appropriate to show Features section as shown in sscreenshot given below?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
![screenshot of page i am working on][1]
```

[image]

Here is the features section where i have used list of bootstrap, but i don't like the look and feel of it so please suggest me any good bootstrap component for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of nice solutions online.
Personally, I like to see a list of Features as you can see in the following example:
[Portfolio Template](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/)

[image]

You can simply align your Items horizontally and add some fancy Glyphicon or FontAwesome Icon.
In this example, the required code snippet is as easy as:

```
<!-- Services Section -->
<section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Services</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum   dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">E-Commerce</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">Responsive Design</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
                <h4 class="service-heading">Web Security</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most standard format for showing a list of items is using the bootstrap grid system to separate the content into 3 columns, as can be seen on [Airbnb's landing page](https://www.airbnb.com/) (scroll down below the jumbotron).

Here's the documentation for the Bootstrap grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

In it's simplest form, you would want to separate a group of three features into something like such to replicate the example layout provided above:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p> Feature 1 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p> Feature 2 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p> Feature 1 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know nothing right out of the box gives you the desired effect. However, the easiest way to do this is with lists. See the snipped and fiddle below.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjv9kbqw/)**

```css
body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
.features {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 15px auto;
}
.features > li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.features > li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-unstyled features">
    <li>Feature 000</li>
    <li>Feature 001</li>
    <li>Feature 002</li>
    <li>Feature 003</li>
    <li>Feature 004</li>
</ul>
```